# Angular server side paginate with skip and take

Tags: angularjs

I have a route like below : 
`http://example.com/centers?skip=1&take=2`
I want to make an angular table pagination with that route 
  Pagination parameter be skip and take 
I want to parse this parameter on client side and make request to server side
How can I make that paginate with angular?

Comment: Do you want serverside pagination or clientside, downloading all data from server?

Comment: serverside  , that route parameter created from server

Comment: could you add some code, what you tried so far.. code with working plunkr/fiddle would be good.. Thanks

Comment: Is such case you have to parse this params on client side and make request to server side increasing this params...

Comment: i used a sample from [this link](http://code.ciphertrick.com/demo/server-pagination/) but does not exist  skip and take parameter that sample

Comment: yes i want to parse this parameter on client and make request to sever side

Comment: No one can not help me?